# The backup solution (for system disruption / non-data backup)

Tags: performance

We have encountered several performance impacts in the last few weeks. Although, the root-cause is reported in the trust.salesforce.com, the risk still exists and the service disruption can happen in another day, and we are worry about it.

Do people here have the same issue as we have ? And, what's the service-level backup solutions are recommended ?

(1) To use the ***performance edition*** is a way to prevent (lower) the risk of performance degradation ?

(2) Or, shouldn't we run the critical system in the salesforce cloud platform at the moment until there's a SLA and say we can have 99.999% ?

(3) Or, any other suggestions are welcome..

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are aware that 99.999% uptime means something like 5 minutes of actual downtime per year, right? Salesforce is nowhere near that, especially if you consider the many partial outages and disruptions, slowdowns, etc. Heck if you look at trust.salesforce.com right now, you'll see there's only been something like 11 days in the last 30 where there were no reportable incidents across all nodes.

You're going to be hard-pressed to find 99.999% in a SaaS SLA. Even when it is (for instance several online providers "guarantee" 99.95%), you'll find many SaaS providers routinely violate that SLA but your contractual recourse is generally not much better than some partial credit that is based on the amount of downtime.

So, first thing to validate is do you really need 24/7 99.999% uptime? If you are sure that you do, and partial credit for a provider going below that is not acceptable recourse (it wouldn't be if you really need 99.999%), your best option will be to host a data copy yourself, in a physical secure data center that you have total control over. Or in multiple controlled data centers. You could also host in multiple data centers with a co-location provider that has a good track record of security and uptime.

There are quite a few types of workable approaches to shadowing your SFDC data to other data centers. So you could use SFDC as the data front-end for management of data, but for serving it to whatever service you have that has the 99.999% requirement, you go straight from your hosted "data warehouse" that has 99.999%.

Even still, you'll find that managing under 5 minutes of downtime per year is harder than it sounds, even with multiple redundancy. It takes a lot of money and effort to actually achieve.

Comment: Fwiw, salesforce.com did have a [five nines month](http://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2006/04/060411-1.jsp), but I agree with this answer. Five nines is nearly impossible. I can't even keep my own computer at home running 99.999% of the time (restarts, patches, etc). Salesforce is still a cheaper option than a home brew solution if you want well over 99% reliability (IT staff 24x7 costs more, not including hardware, power). Great job!

Answer (score 2):

Performance edition is just a feature set...still runs on the same instances and subject to the same failures and maintenance periods.

If you can get that SLA from somebody, let us know.  We didn't get it from AWS or internal.  Google might be a good option.

Comment: Not even Google provides real 99.999% uptime. According to this post (http://blog.vercer.com/2013/01/whats-real-uptime-for-google-app-engine.html), they're more like 99.87%.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of the clients I work for their internal systems are not as available as Salesforce. But one thing to note is when salesforce does upgrade it maybe unavailable for around 5minutes. If you are a global company make sure you sign up for an org in the country that requires the most availability otherwise you may find updates happening during the day.

Comment: There're two kind of schedule downtime. While major upgrade takes 5 minutes, the schedule maintenance takes 3 hours or longer.